# Magit-todos warning: File is too long, consider excluding it from scans

Tags: magit

Whenever I do something in Magit buffer I get this warning:

```
Warning (magit-todos): File has lines too long for Emacs to search.  Consider excluding it from scans: path/to/file
```

In particular it complains about socket.io.js.map

I tried excluding the file from projectile - no effect. I don't understand which scans the warning is talking about.

Comment: Try adding the offending file pattern to [`magit-todos-exclude-globs`](https://github.com/alphapapa/magit-todos/blob/a80dace2bf8bf3e697e3e8421189996adcecc900/magit-todos.el#L324).

Comment: Tobias, thanks, that worked. Here is a readme explaining in details how to do it: https://github.com/alphapapa/magit-todos#tips Another question: the exclude  patterns in magit-todos-exclude-globs are the same as in .gitignore? Is there any docs on patterns otherwise?

Comment: You can [see it yourself](https://github.com/alphapapa/magit-todos/blob/a80dace2bf8bf3e697e3e8421189996adcecc900/magit-todos.el#L1244-L1257). A string consisting of  `:!` and the glob-pattern is appended to the `git` command behind `--`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could write up your own answer and accept it. I don't have time for that right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `magit-todos-exclude-globs` variable.

It can be set globally:

```el
(setq magit-todos-exclude-globs '(patterns))
```

in config or locally, per-repository.

To set it locally, run `add-dir-local-variable`, choose `magit-status-mode`, choose `magit-todos-exclude-globs`, add patterns you would like to exclude as a list.

Example: `("*.map" "*.html")`

That will generate `.dir-locals.el` with the appropriate configuration.